# Скрыть строку, которая подходит под условие

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть DataGridView, там 3 колонки: имя, возраст и стипендия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть задачи в том, что нужно скрывать тех, у кого нет стипендии, через кнопочку или чекбокс. Я сделал заполнение, временно рандомом, а вот основную задачу не могу выполнить. Не соображаю как проверить ячейку на 0 и скрыть именно эту строку. Думаю, через цикл, но не могу собрать этот конструктор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как именно осуществляется заполнение грида? Привязка данных используется?

Comment: нет, я их заполняю рандомом или ручками (http://prntscr.com/lqwkbf)
Косо-криво но мне пока только скрывать нужно

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать это таким образом но понимаю что эта штука не работает
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == "0")
                {
                    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Visible = false;
                }
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В цикле перебираете все строки, проверяете значение определенной ячейки `Cells[Index]` на условие, и скрываете полностью строку.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  if (row.Cells[2].Value != null && (int)row.Cells[2].Value == 0)
  {
    row.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

Что бы не получить исключение, добавил проверку на `null`,
`row.Cells[2].Value != null` последняя строка в таблице может быть пустая.

Что бы корректно сравнивались значение, преобразуйте `object` к `int` 
`(int)row.Cells[2].Value == 0`

Comment: Я немного не сообразил, сделал цикл там выставил чтобы он ходил до 10, и поставил вместо   row.Cells[Index].Value == 0   ---  row.Cells[i].Value
Выбрасывает ошибку. Да и проверять я решил еще на строку http://prntscr.com/lqyptv
Что не так делаю?

Comment: 1. Вам не надо использовать цикл `for`. `foreach` сам пройдет по всем строкам. 
2. В `Cells[Index]` укажите номер столбца, в котором нужно проверять значение.
3. У Вас текстовое значение или числовое хранится в таблице? Если числовое, ноль в кавычки брать не нужно.

Comment: В условии `if (row.Cells[Index].Value == 0)` если не брать в кавычки получается ошибка _оператор "==" невозможно применить к операнду типа 'object' и 'int'_

Я сделал вот так - http://prntscr.com/lqzf82

Comment: @ДмитрийКотовский, обновил ответ.

Comment: Бож оно работает, правда выдает ошибку когда 0 вручную в ячейку прописываю но то что генерирует рандом то скрывает, пойдет на первое время. Логику я уже понял. Спасибо огромное)

Comment: @ДмитрийКотовский, если Вы будете менять в ручную. Вам тогда надо изменить условие проверки. `row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "0"`. Ошибка не будет вылетать.